# Xamarin foreground service notification won't change its text

Tags: c#, xamarin, service, notifications, foreground

I use a foreground service that starts normally, my first notification displays, but although the `NotificationManager.Notify()` method runs normally without errors, the notification text won't change. I tried debugging, code runs perfectly every 1s by a timer but update is just not happening.   - It must update to `Datetime.Now`

Inside my service class:

```
 private void ActivityTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        updateNotification();
    }

    private NotificationChannel createNotificationChannel()
    {
        var channelId = Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID;
        var channelName = "My Notification Service";
        var Channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, Android.App.NotificationImportance.None);
        Channel.LightColor = Android.Resource.Color.HoloBlueBright;
        Channel.LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public;
        return Channel;
    }

    private void createForegroundService()
    {
        var mNotificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            mNotificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(createNotificationChannel());
        }
        var notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID);
        var notification = getNotification();
        StartForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

    }
    private void updateNotification()
    {
        var mNotificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            mNotificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(createNotificationChannel());
        }

        var notification = getNotification();

        mNotificationManager.Notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private Notification getNotification()
    {
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this,0,new Intent(this,typeof(MainActivity)),0);
        return new Notification.Builder(this,Constants.NOTIFICATION_CHANNELID)
            .SetColor(Android.Resource.Color.DarkerGray)
            .SetContentTitle("My service name")
            .SetOngoing(true)
            .SetContentText(DateTime.Now.ToString("T"))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.notification_icon_background)
            .SetContentIntent(pIntent).Build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was here:
`var Channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, Android.App.NotificationImportance.**None**);`
<- Leave it to `NotificationImportance.Default`